# Why can't I create a .ssh directory on macOS 10.15.4?

Tags: macos, catalina, unix, ssh, apfs

I'm running into a strange problem trying to set up ssh. I'm more used to Linux than macOS. Can someone explain to me what's going on here?

```
user@nothing ~ % mkdir ~/.ssh
mkdir: /Users/user: No such file or directory
user@nothing ~ % ls -ld ~
drwxr-xr-x+ 27 user  staff  864 Apr  1 13:49 /Users/user
user@nothing ~ % ls -ld ~/.ssh
ls: /Users/user/.ssh: No such file or directory
```

The ACLs are defined as:

```
nnyby@nothing ~ % ls -ael ~
total 96
drwxr-xr-x+ 26 nnyby  staff    832 Apr  2 09:47 .
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   admin    192 Oct 23 20:37 ..
-r--------   1 nnyby  staff      7 Mar 28 11:24 .CFUserTextEncoding
-rw-r--r--@  1 nnyby  staff   6148 Apr  1 13:44 .DS_Store
drwx------  10 nnyby  staff    320 Apr  1 13:44 .Trash
-rw-------   1 nnyby  staff    751 Apr  1 13:43 .bash_history
drwx------  41 nnyby  staff   1312 Nov  7 14:29 .bash_sessions
drwx------   3 nnyby  staff     96 Nov 15 11:40 .config
drwxr-xr-x   4 nnyby  staff    128 Nov  1 11:27 .emacs.d
-rw-r--r--   1 nnyby  staff     53 Nov 13 12:28 .gitconfig
drwx------   3 nnyby  staff     96 Nov 15 11:40 .local
-rw-------   1 nnyby  staff    118 Mar 22 09:59 .python_history
-rw-------   1 nnyby  staff  12554 Apr  1 19:37 .viminfo
-rw-------   1 nnyby  staff   5271 Apr  2 09:21 .zsh_history
drwx------@  3 nnyby  staff     96 Apr  1 09:53 Applications
drwx------+ 14 nnyby  staff    448 Apr  1 22:56 Desktop
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 10 nnyby  staff    320 Apr  2 09:47 Documents
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 25 nnyby  staff    800 Apr  1 22:39 Downloads
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 66 nnyby  staff   2112 Apr  1 09:52 Library
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  4 nnyby  staff    128 Nov 25 14:23 Movies
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  4 nnyby  staff    128 Mar 17 20:50 Music
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+ 30 nnyby  staff    960 Apr  1 22:39 Pictures
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+  4 nnyby  staff    128 Oct 24 14:34 Public
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   4 nnyby  staff    128 Mar 20 10:40 dist
drwxr-xr-x   9 nnyby  staff    288 Apr  1 14:12 src
nnyby@nothing ~ % ls -ael ~/..
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   6 root      admin  192 Oct 23 20:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root      admin  704 Mar 28 11:54 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel    0 Oct 17 18:40 .localized
drwxrwxrwt   5 root      wheel  160 Oct 17 18:40 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 11 ctladmin  staff  352 Oct 24 14:34 ctladmin
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x+ 26 nnyby     staff  832 Apr  2 09:47 nnyby
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

Similarly, I can't generate public and private keys:

```
user@nothing ~ % ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Could not create directory '/Users/user/.ssh': No such file or directory
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Saving key "/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory
```

I can create a dot-prefixed directory with another name, no problem:

```
user@nothing ~ % mkdir ~/.abc
user@nothing ~ %
```

If I do `mkdir /tmp/.ssh; mv /tmp/.ssh ~/`, the `mv` process hangs, and uses all my CPU until I restart!

So, how do I make my `.ssh` directory?

Comment: None of the ACL explain why you can't create `~/.ssh`, they only impact deletion of default directories. Hmm.

Comment: @klanomath I've added the `a` flag to my `ls` commands above. `cd ~/ && mkdir .ssh` returns `mkdir: .: No such file or directory`.

Comment: `mkdir: .: No such file or directory`, you are sure about this? Would expect `mkdir: .ssh: No file...`. Can you copy/paste the commands directly from your comment and rerun them (maybe you type a special character by accident)?

Comment: @nohillside here is a screenshot if you don't believe me! https://i.imgur.com/G3rp949.png
In text form: https://dpaste.org/d7it/raw

Comment: I believe you :-) I don't trust the output, and special characters won't show up in the screenshot either.

Comment: @klanomath interesting. Yes, `user` = `nnyby`. I just changed that for this post. I don't think my mac is bound to an Active Directory. I'm using a local user here. Is there something I can do to determine that for sure?

Comment: @klanomath I'm looking at the source code of `mkdir` right now, looks like the `mkdir()` system calls fails.

Comment: @klanomath ah okay, so yeah. I'm not joined to any Network Account Server.

Comment: @nnyby Did you already verify the various volumes with Disk Utility and do you have any AntiVirus/AntiMalware/InternetProtection app running?

Comment: What is the result of `type -p mkdir`?

Comment: @nohillside `mkdir is /bin/mkdir`

Comment: @klanomath I haven't verified the volumes.. it looks like I need to boot into recovery mode to do that. I'll try that in a bit, I'm using my laptop right now for work.

I don't see any antivirus apps running on here, or anything like that.

Comment: Can you check `/var/log/system.log` at the time you try to `mkdir`?

Comment: @nohillside I don't see anything happen as a direct result of my mkdir, but there are a bunch of messages like this that are constantly going through my `/var/log/system.log`: https://dpaste.org/r5h5/raw

Comment: That's odd. Can you create the `.ssh` folder through Finder using [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788836/1256347)?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke When I follow those steps, the folder gets renamed to "untitled folder". When I try to delete this folder, I get the message "“untitled folder” can’t be opened right now because it’s being used by another task, such as moving or copying an item or emptying the Trash. Try again when the current task is complete."

Comment: Well, that doesn't sound hopeful. Next step I would try is to create a [new user account](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac) and see if the issue persists there. If not, I would move over to that new account as this sounds pretty hard to diagnose.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I will try making a new user but I mean.. I am the admin of this account. Is there no way to fix the issue? Shit, I'll just go back to Linux. Screw this!

Comment: @klanomath https://dpaste.org/JH0b/raw

Answer (score 1):

I booted into recovery mode, and ran First Aid on my disk. First the Macintosh HD volume, which returned without error.

Then, when I ran First Aid on the "Macintosh HD - Data" volume, the operation failed, with these errors:

[image: First Aid run, pic 1]

[image: First Aid run, pic 2]

I ran this operation twice, with the same errors. I didn't know what else to do, so I just restarted back into the normal environment.

When I log in, I see that there is a `.ssh` directory after all, created last October 25!

```
nnyby@nothing ~ % ls -lae .ssh
total 24
drwx------   5 nnyby  staff   160 Oct 25 11:36 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 26 nnyby  staff   832 Apr  2 12:43 ..
 0: group:everyone deny delete
-rw-------   1 nnyby  staff  1856 Oct 25 11:36 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--   1 nnyby  staff   423 Oct 25 11:36 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 nnyby  staff  3192 Apr  2 12:46 known_hosts
```

I had restarted this laptop plenty of times over the past few weeks, always with this `.ssh` problem, so maybe the disk repair did something to fix it? Either way, thank you macOS for being completely not frustrating at all to work with! I can't imagine why anyone would prefer to use Linux!

Comment: I'm not sure if a broken filesystem is unique to macOS, this can happen in a Linux machine as well, right? Also, without fixing the underlying issue I expect you to keep having a frustrating experience sooner or later. So perhaps you can reformat and restore a backup?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke The difference is that, on the rare occasion I happen to have a broken filesystem in Linux, it repairs itself on boot. This is a brand new Apple laptop that my office bought for me, and with this APFS volume, even when booting into a separate recovery mode, the problem wasn't resolved. I don't want to reformat and restore a backup... I don't have another hard drive or the resources to do that! I'll just see if I can install Linux on here, unless Apple's T2 chip prevents that...

Comment: The largest (or a reasonable large) backup disk equals 1/10 (or 1/30) of the price of a new MBP!

Comment: @klanomath I agree, apple's laptops are wayyyy overpriced! >_< haha

Comment: True! On the other hand at least one fifth of the problems leading to a question here (at apple.stackexchange) could have been avoided/solved quickly if the persons asking have had a backup...

Comment: @nnyby It's a pity that you have such a bad experience with a new mac, perhaps you can exchange it? I doubt that it came out of the box with this error though. Also, not having a backup will lead to a guaranteed bad experience, regardless if using macOS or Linux. Perhaps your office can provide you with a HDD or some server storage?

Comment: I never back shit up, and that's not a solution! The OS should be able to take care of this on its own. Reformat and reinstall is not a solution! This isn't Windows.

Comment: `I never back shit up` Good luck!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke you don't need to blame me for this problem. Obviously there are bugs in macOS here that I'm trying to get to the bottom of. I'm interested in any feedback related to this problem, not my personal habits related to HD backups.